# Genre-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be appropriate to create tags for (broad) genres? For example, mixing heavy metal is much different than mixing folk music... instances like that. I think it'd be useful.

Comment: Define broad, and how would it be enforced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree these add useful information, but I'd add that genre tags should only be added if it is relevant to the question.  For example, if I'm asking about how to copy tracks in my DAW it probably doesn't matter whether I'm working with hip-hop or classical music.

Comment: Yes, of course that would be the case.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think genre specific tags would add much to the site.

On the contrary, I think it would be a slippery slope of people defining genres and sub-genres differently.  I think there would end up being (if they were regularly used) a large number of low population tags.

Also, I think it ventures very close to the meta-tag variety.   Check out [this blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  Quick summary:

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might
>   think.
>
> 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
>      meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>      the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective],
>      and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you
>      nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. If the tag commonly
>      means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.
>      In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself …
>      is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner].
>      Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are
>      impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective
>      metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and
>      [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Also, the question is not about the music (or at least it shouldn't be).  If the type of music is really that integral to the question, it can certainly be a part of the title, meaning it's still searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually thinking about this the other day, when mixing something like metal guitars (which I do often) or mixing DnB drums, I would like to be able to tag it metal or dnb or something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the term 'genre' is that it can be too ambiguous.  Many musicians often resort to inventing their own sub-genre, which could dilute the focus of a tag.  I don't think it would be worth anyone's while getting into arguments over what does and doesn't constitute a genre.

If we're going for overall audio scape here, I think it would suffice to describe the type of sound you're going for in a question.  For example; how do I process the drum kit to give it a large, aggressive sound?  Here are some example tracks (that may well be from the metal genre).

Another thing to think of, is the fact that this site aims to be both an audio *and* video production site.  Attempting to cover all genres in both audio and video, even broadly, could make tags too vague.

Comment: +1 "what does and doesn't constitute a genre" -- exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Fine for me. If the question is about heavy metal, having a tag that denotes this is very useful...